# Is my php code fine to all special characters of username?

Tags: php, authentication

I am having a problem to include all special characters that a user may use while entering it on sign up page like space,@, '.' etc. I have used the below one:-

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["user_login"]) && isset($_POST["password_login"])) {
$user_login = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9@._\(\)\']#i', '', $_POST["user_login"]);
$password_login = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9!@._]#i', '', $_POST["password_login"]);
$md5password_login = md5($password_login);
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$user_login' AND password='$md5password_login' LIMIT 1");
//check for their existance
$userCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); //count the number of rows returned
if ($userCount == 1) {
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {

$id = $row["id"];
}
$_SESSION["id"] = $id;
$_SESSION["user_login"] = $user_login;
$_SESSION["password_login"] = $password_login;
exit("<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0\">");
} else {
echo "Your Username or Password is Incorrect. please try again.";
exit();
}
}
?>
```

and my form is like this :-

```
<form method="post" action="index.php" id="login_form" name="login_form">
          <table border="" style="border:none">
            <tr>
              <td ><input type="text" tabindex="1"  id="email" placeholder="Username or Phone" name="user_login" class="inputtext radius1" value="" autofocus="autofocus"/></td>
              <td ><input type="password" tabindex="2" id="pass" placeholder="Password" name="password_login" class="inputtext radius1"/></td>
              <td ><input type="submit" class="hpbutton" name="button" value="Log In" /></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </form>
```

Is this code okay with my requirements?

Comment: Stripping characters out of the user's password is a *super* bad idea. Also, `mysql_query` is deprecated. It's being removed from the language, and you shouldn't be using it.

Comment: yeah i know that it is going to be deprecated. i will change it later.

Comment: Those are some famous last words if I ever heard them. That should be on a tshirt for programmers.

Comment: "later" is lame, change it now, while you're not too into building on top of it

Comment: okay.i am changing it.fine !

Comment: I'll take two @meagar 1x Med. and 1 Large. ;-)

Comment: You are using [an unsuitable hashing algorithm](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) and need to [take better care](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) of your users' passwords.